# WebRTC PeerConnection is not establishing in CHROME and EDGE

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Below is the code for establishing peer connection from WEBRTC CLIENT and I am getting error `Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object`. There is no problem with signaling server, socket.io or turn/stun servers.

Surprisingly it works MIRACLOUSLY in Firefox,but not in Chrome and Edge.  Your kind help is greatly appreciated.

### CODE

```
function createRTC(id, callback) {
    participants[id] = {}
    console.log(id)
    try {
        participants[id].pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: " + e.message);
       ** alert("Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.");**
        return;
    }
```

Expecting proper Webrtc connection between clients.

Comment: What does the console.log show? This should help determining whether the error is specific to WebRTC or a generic one like `pc_config` not being defined.

Comment: MediaStream {id: 'e96e76ac-1b96-45ff-8bc4-0f800c521b36', active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …} MediaStream {id: 'ca3b037e-98a7-4e62-9f48-cd410342f3d6', active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null, …}

[JOINED]
webrtc.js?v=0.2:147 [USER JOINED] [creating offer] nu3DX-aKS8nbiwNFAAAL
webrtc.js?v=0.2:235 nu3DX-aKS8nbiwNFAAAL
webrtc.js?v=0.2:239 Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: Failed to construct 'RTCPeerConnection': 'stun:ediequate.org:3478?transport=udp' is not a valid stun or turn URL.

Comment: Please refer above @PhilippHancke I believe the STUN URL is valid though because it is working in firefox.  Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: It is *not* valid, STUN urls are not allowed to have a ?transport=udp and is rejected in recent Chrome versions (that include the fix for https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1385735).
Remove the "?transport=udp" and it should be fine.